# Encrypt SQL Server connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, connection-string

If one has a connectionstring in one's application, is there a way to encrypt the information it contains?

The connection string is created using the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` object.

Or is it 'acceptable' that sensitive information is sent in plaintext to the server?

Comment: So what do you want to encryt? The (local) sql connection string that configures the client access? Or the communication on the wire between a client and a remote user? I understand you're using SQL users, not windows authentication?

Comment: I want to mainly encrypt the password that is sent on the wire to the server in the connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can use AES for example, to encrypt the data, send the encrypted connection string to the database computer. on that computer you need to build a listener that is getting the encrypted connection string and then decrypt it and connect to server. you need to build a softwere between the database computer and the user computer if you want to encrypt\decrypt all the data, but for the ConnectionString that the way...(encrypt -> send it to the server to a listener -> decrypt)

Hope it helps.
Amit.

Answer (score 1):

Hope [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(VS.80).aspx) helps.

> Is it 'acceptable' that sensitive information is sent in plaintext to the server?

It depends on how much level of security you want for you application, as security critical apps might need encryption of the connection string.

Use encryption sparingly and judiciously though - **there is a performance hit**.

Edit: Changed the link, Linked to MSDN (more info)

Thanks

Comment: This is good, but as my connection string is created at runtime in my application, I cannot place it in a app.config file.